# Silverlight doesn't try to get clientaccesspolicy.xml

Tags: silverlight, wcf

This question comes from this other one:
[Consuming WCF Service through https from Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125746/consuming-wcf-service-through-https-from-silverlight)

After trying EVERYTHING to ensure this is not a certificate problem I have realize that silverlight doesn't even try to get the clientaccesspolicy.xml file (fiddler said that :-P).

Can anybody realize why?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SSL, you should setup fiddler in order to [Decrypting HTTPS-protected traffic](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp)

Try [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/03/07/enabling-cross-domain-calls-for-silverlight-apps-on-self-hosted-web-services.aspx) and host your ClientAccessPolicyService on the the SSL port.

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy in Silverlight to accidentally go to localhost instead of the desired server when using WCF, and Fiddler won't show this by default, but you can [turn it on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214308/how-do-i-get-fiddler-to-stop-ignoring-traffic-to-localhost). Apologies if you've already checked this.

Comment: On fact, my WCF service should be on localhost because I'm just testing it before going into production... It's showing all my localhost traffic but nothing for my clientaccesspolicy.xml. Thanks anyway for your answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight does not attempt to retrieve clientaccesspolicy.xml on localhost.

That probably makes sense as each service/website is run up on separate dev port number so there is no localhost port 80 by default while debugging. i.e. where should it get the file from?

Comment: It should get it from "https://samsung/clientaccesspolicy.xml" where samsung is localhost... If it shouldn't get it, I can't imagine why I'm getting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125746/consuming-wcf-service-through-https-from-silverlight

Comment: @zapico: samsung is a dns name in that other question, so it is the actual root of the web site. Silverlight will only search the root of the web site (or a subdomain) for clientaccesspolicy.xml You can't do that with localhost alone